# Create Large'sh 3D in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I'm trying to render some 3D content in a WPF window.  When loaded it renders fine however it takes a noticeable length of time to load the Model.  I attempted to make this as fast as possible by writing a direct intialization of the Model3D ex.

```
Model3D model = new GeometryModel3D(new MeshGeometry3D{Positions=new Point3DCollection{new Point3D(x,y,z),... },
                                                       Normals=new Vector3DCollection{new Vector3D(x,y,z),... },
                                                       TriangleIndices=new Int32Collection{1,2,3,... }}, 
                                                       new DiffuseMaterial(...));
```

This works and I thought it would be the fastest considering no parsing involved etc.  However it still takes a fair time to complete and because it happens on the GUI thread it stalls the UI during loading.

I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a faster way to load static data like this.
2. How could I load this data in another thread.  All of these 3D objects are derived fro `DispatcherObject` which can only be accessed from the creating thread.  I have played around but all the options look like the still involve copying the data item by item

Comment: I would use `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {  \\Create Model here }` and use data binding in xaml

Comment: As always with performance issues, a profiler is your best friend. I would also at least try to load the model from file instead. If you lack an importer, there are some included in the HelixToolkit library.